# Method to execute commands

Tags: java, methods

I have a about 100 calls of external methods from my own code.

Now I try to perform some actions before and after one of those methods is called.

Is there a way to define a method with an argument containing an other method/block of code, that should be performed? I know this would be highly risky, but overloading 100 of methods within a code I'm not able to edit is also no fun.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: your text is a bit weird, im not getting the question :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a cross cutting concern, you should look into [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (Aspect Oriented Programming).

The Spring Framework allows to implement before advice, after advice and around advice, which seems what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to define a method with an argument containing an other command that should be performed?

Well, yes. For instance:

```
public interface Command
{
    void doSomething();
}
```

then you could call your method with an argument of type `Command`. All you "have to do" is provide implementations of this interface. For instance:

```
public void doCommand(final Command command)
{
    command.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: OP's question now reads "*with an argument containing an other method/block of code*".

Comment: I honestly do not see how. Could you please explain? It seems that OP needs something like function pointers in C.

Comment: Which cannot be done in Java. You have to go through interfaces like the one I wrote. Even though Java 8 will have a syntax which is easier on the eyes, deep down, this will be the same: you provide implementations of interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
    todo(System.out.println("t"));

    public void todo(String a){
    runtime.exec(a);
    }
```